# How to have your app notified whenever iPhone is turned on or will be turned off?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, state

Is there any way my app can be notified (even if it's not in use or background) whenever the user turns his iPhone on and a few moments before it is turned off?
Thank you since now. This is needed in order to know how much time has the phone been off.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, and it's obviously hard to debug to find out what is happening. It would make sense that your app is moved to the background. If it is in the background, it shouldn't really matter whether the phone is turned on or off.

You can look at file encryption; if the user uses a passcode then you will be notified when encrypted files cannot be accessed anymore, and when they can again be accessed. That will happen when the phone is turned off or on.

Comment: Clever, is it a well known way to do so?

Comment: Gnasher, it's a nice solution, but as you said it would only work if the user uses encryption. I've edited my question explaining why I need to use such function. Do you have any idea? Thank you anyway for your answer!